# Add multiple routers with different router class to the same endpoints in FastAPI

Tags: python, fastapi

I have a /users route in my app which is initialized with a default router like this :

(Note that responses and dependencies have been removed from the snippet to protect proprietary code)

```
api_router = APIRouter(
    responses={},
    route_class=LocalizationRoute,
    dependencies=[],
)
```

Localization Route is being used directly from fastapi-localizationpackage for translation purpose.

Now I want to add another router to the same route for the purpose of logging . This router is based on the following router class

```
def log_info(req_body, res_body):
    print(req_body)
    print(res_body)


class LoggingRoute(APIRoute):
    def get_route_handler(self) -> Callable:
        original_route_handler = super().get_route_handler()

        async def custom_route_handler(request: Request) -> Response:
            req_body = await request.body()
            response = await original_route_handler(request)

            if isinstance(response, StreamingResponse):
                res_body = b''
                async for item in response.body_iterator:
                    res_body += item

                task = BackgroundTask(log_info, req_body, res_body)
                return Response(content=res_body, status_code=response.status_code,
                                headers=dict(response.headers), media_type=response.media_type, background=task)
            else:
                res_body = response.body
                response.background = BackgroundTask(log_info, req_body, res_body)
                return response

        return custom_route_handler
```

I tried doing this by using `include`*`router` clause like this :

`api_`*`router.include_`*`router(APIRouter(router`*`_class= LoggingRoute))`

But this is not working. I can see the router class is still set to Localization Route and the router*class argument in `include_`*`router`  statement is ignored.

So I was wondering do fast api not support adding multiple routers with different router class to the same route ?

Comment: Why do you use the `django` tag?

Comment: Wasn't sure if something similar happens in django too. Thought it might bring more perspective to the answers